# Не могу поймать конец файла

Tags: c++, fstream

Задача состоит в проверке баланса фигурных скобок в файле. Читаю файл посимвольно, однако программа зацикливается (не отлавливается конец файла). Что я делаю не так?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int flag=0, ctr=0;
    char с;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    ifstream fin("text.txt");
    fin >> с;
    while (с!=EOF)
    {
        if (с == '{')
            ctr += 1;
        if (с == '}')
            ctr -= 1;
        if (ctr < 0)
            flag = 1;
        fin >> с;
    }
    fin.close();
    if ((ctr == 0) && (flag == 0))
        cout << "OK" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not OK" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вместо `ctr+=1; ctr-=1;` лучше писать `++ctr; --ctr;`. Это больше соответствует "стилю С"

Comment: Спасибо, как то машинально получилась помарка, но дело то не в ней

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
while (с!=EOF)
```

на

```
while (fin)
```

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

`while (с!=EOF)` изменить на `while((c = getc(f)) != EOF)`. При каждой следующей итерации `c` будет иметь значение следующего символа файла.

```
int main() {
    FILE* f;
    char c;
    int ctr = 0, flag = 0;    

    f = fopen("G:\\Other\\stackoverflow\\f.txt", "r");

    while((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '{') ctr++;
        if (c == '}') ctr--;
    }

    fclose(f);

    if (ctr < 0) flag = 1;

    if ((ctr == 0) && (flag == 0)) {
        cout << "OK";
    }
    else {
        cout << "NOT OK";
    }

    return 0;
}
```